# Clean way to compute transition probabilities between two columns of a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, probability

Toy example:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
n_people <- 100
groups <- c("A", "B", "C")
example_table <- data.table(person_id=seq_len(n_people),
                            group_2010=sample(groups, n_people, TRUE),
                            group_2011=sample(groups, n_people, TRUE))

## Error-prone and requires lots of typing -- programmatic alternative?
transition_probs <- example_table[, list(pr_A_2011=mean(group_2011=="A"),
                                         pr_B_2011=mean(group_2011=="B"),
                                         pr_C_2011=mean(group_2011=="C")),
                                         by=group_2010]
transition_probs  # Essentially a transition matrix giving Pr[group_2011 | group_2010]

#    group_2010 pr_A_2011 pr_B_2011 pr_C_2011
# 1:          A 0.1481481 0.5185185 0.3333333
# 2:          B 0.3684211 0.3947368 0.2368421
# 3:          C 0.3142857 0.3142857 0.3714286
```

The "manual" approach above is fine when the groups are A, B, C, but gets messy if there are more groups (or if we just have the `groups` vector but don't know ahead of time what it contains).

Is there a "data.table way" to compute the transition_probs object in my example code above?  Can list(pr_A_2011=...) be replaced with something programmatic?

My concern is that, if I add a group D, I will have to edit the code in multiple places, notably by typing `pr_D_2011=mean(group_2011=="D")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do

```
lvls = example_table[, sort(unique(c(group_2010, group_2011))) ]
x = dcast(example_table, group_2010~group_2011)[, N := Reduce(`+`,.SD), .SDcols=lvls]

#    group_2010  A  B  C  N
# 1:          A  6  9 15 30
# 2:          B 15  4 12 31
# 3:          C 11 11 17 39
```

From here, if you want transition probabilities, just divide by `N`:

```
x[, (lvls) := lapply(.SD,`/`, x$N), .SDcols=lvls]
# or, with data.table 1.9.7+
x[, (lvls) := lapply(.SD,`/`, N), .SDcols=lvls]

#    group_2010         A         B         C  N
# 1:          A 0.1481481 0.5185185 0.3333333 27
# 2:          B 0.3684211 0.3947368 0.2368421 38
# 3:          C 0.3142857 0.3142857 0.3714286 35
```

Answer (score 2):

The design of `data.table` is intentionally meant to be compatible with operations on `data.frames`, so unless you can (a) prove this operation is a huge bottleneck and (b) demonstrate that alternate solutions are significantly faster, why not stick with brevity and clarity:

```
prop.table(table(example_table[,2:3,with=FALSE]),1)
```

```
          group_2011
group_2010         A         B         C
         A 0.1481481 0.5185185 0.3333333
         B 0.3684211 0.3947368 0.2368421
         C 0.3142857 0.3142857 0.3714286
```

Comment: Thank you -- I actually didn't know about `prop.table`!

Answer (score 1):

I see both current answers very well addressing your question. I will answer then handling it in a more generic manner.
If you want real programmatic power you can use [computing on the language](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Computing-on-the-language) R language feature.

> R belongs to a class of programming languages in which subroutines have the ability to modify or construct other subroutines and evaluate the result as an integral part of the language itself.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
n_people <- 100
groups <- c("A", "B", "C")
example_table <- data.table(person_id=seq_len(n_people),
                            group_2010=sample(groups, n_people, TRUE),
                            group_2011=sample(groups, n_people, TRUE))
f = function(data, groups, years) {
    stopifnot(is.data.table(data), length(groups) > 0L, length(years) == 2L, paste0("group_", years) %in% names(data))
    j.names = sprintf("pr_%s_%s", c(groups), years[2L])
    j.vals = lapply(setNames(groups, j.names), function(group) call("mean", call("==", as.name(sprintf("group_%s", years[2L])), group)))
    jj = as.call(c(list(as.name(".")), j.vals))
    data[, eval(jj), by = c(sprintf("group_%s", years[1L]))]
}
f(example_table, groups, 2010:2011)
#   group_2010 pr_A_2011 pr_B_2011 pr_C_2011
#1:          A 0.1481481 0.5185185 0.3333333
#2:          B 0.3684211 0.3947368 0.2368421
#3:          C 0.3142857 0.3142857 0.3714286
```

No need to replace code in few places, just passing arguments to function.